# How does real world login process happen in web application in Java?

Tags: java

I am very much confused regarding login process that happen in Java web application. I read many tutorials regarding jdbcRealm and JAAS. But, one thing that i don't understand is that why should i use them ? Can't i simply check directly against my database of users? and once they successfully login to the site, i store some variable in session as a flag. And probably check that session variable on all restricted pages (I mean keep a filter for restricted resources url pattern).If the flag doesn't exist simply redirect the user to login page. Is this approach correct?Does this approch sound correct? If yes, then why did all this JAAS and jdbcRealm came into existence?

Secondly, I am trying to completely implement SAS(Software as service) in my web application, meaning everything is done through web services.If i use webservices, is it possible to use jdbcRealm? If not, then is it possible to use JAAS? If yes, then please show me some example which uses mySql as a database and then authenticates and authorizes. I even heard about Spring Security. But, i am confused about that too in the sense that how do i use webservice with Spring Security.

Please help me. I am really very confused. I read sun's tutorials but they only keep talking about theories. For programmers to understand a simple concept, they show a 100 page theory first before they finally come to one example.

Comment: +1 because I share your confusion about JAAS. That seems to be more applicable to client applications than to three-tier-solutions like a typical web application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it yourself.

However these things exists so you don't need to implement it yourself. They're written by very smart people, they're tested, it works. If you want to do this yourself, are you sure you won't introduce any bugs ? Are you sure users won't be able to circumwent the login ? (the last time I saw someone implement this himself, the user could simply bypass all url checking by going to http://site.com/foo/../foo/bar instead of entering the normal URL of http://site.com/foo/bar)

As for an example on how to use e.g. jdbcrealm with Tomcat for basic HTTP authentication see [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/realm-howto.html#JDBCRealm).
You create the tables etc. as described there. In your webapp you create the file
META-INF/context.xml that might look like this:

```
<context>
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm" debug="99"
      driverName="com.mysql.Driver"
   connectionURL="jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb?user=dbuser&amp;password=dbpass"
       userTable="users" userNameCol="user_name" userCredCol="user_pass"
   userRoleTable="user_roles" roleNameCol="role_name"/>
</context>
```

In your WEB-INF/web.xml you add something like this:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>Entire Application</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
      <role-name>USER</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
  </security-constraint>
<login-config>
  <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
  <realm-name>MyWebapp Login</realm-name>
</login-config>
```

(This password protects your entire webapp, you could restrict it to e.g. only the URLs of your web service. Authenticated users that has the role USER will be granted access.

Add a user to the database, with something like this SQL

```
insert into users values('bob','secretpassword');
insert into roles values('bob','USER');
```

You then place the JDBC driver .jar file in $CATALINA_HOME/lib/ and you're good to go.

Comment: Hello nos,
I know how to use jdbcRealm. But i was wondering, how do i use it with webservice? Because my database is remotely located and i do my login process through webservice. How do i use jdbcRealm with webservice? 

Another problem with jdbcRealm is that, it won't let me identify between type of roles? I have some pages that are common between Admin and common user. Now if i use jdbc realm, and the common user accesses the page it will start showing the menu which is actually meant for admin. It won't distinguish between shared resource of Admin and Common User.

Comment: If you want something special for the admin, you inspect the user role by checking the request.isUserInRole(...) and take action accordingly.
It's hard to tell what authenication you do in your web service, if you want to manually do the login(why?) you can't use jdbcrealm. If you simply want to protect the web service there's no difference in using jdbcrealm on a "normal" webapp/url and a web service. If you want to actually log in to the db as the authenticated user, you cannot use jdbc realm (note that almost noone does that, they use a common database user to connect to the database).

Comment: No, I am not talking about logging in to the DB. What i meant is, I have a page say, login.jsf. When i click "log in" button on it, one web service should be called which in turn will call EJB and which in turn will check whether such a user exists in database or not? If the user exists,then is redirected to home else he thrown to login.jsf again. Can this be done in jdbcRealm?

Comment: If you have login forms, you can use forms based login, some info here, http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.4/docs/tutorial/doc/Security5.html . In this case you just tell tomcat where your login.jsp is, and it takes care of checking whether the user is already logged in, checks the username/password against the database, redirects to your  login.jsp if he's not etc, you don't have to do anything in your code to authenticate a user.
(ofcourse, here are limitations-which is why frameworks such as spring security exits, which gives you a lot more freedom and features. arguably at the cost of complexity).

Answer (score 1):

A lot of real world web applications are moving towards [Single Sign On](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on) functionality. What they do is quite similar to what you have described i.e. there will be some kind of agent running on your application that will intercept the requests and check the cookies, session, authentication etc. with some external server that is responsible for maintaining a database of users, permissions, groups, roles etc. Depending on how you have configured it requests will be allowed or disallowed.

The main point here is that you should be able to write your application without bothering *too much* about cross cutting functionalities like authentication, authorization etc.

You can take look at [OpenSSO](https://opensso.dev.java.net/), [OpenSSO wiki](http://wikis.sun.com/display/OpenSSO/getstarted), [others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_single_sign-on_implementations)